# Record datatype equivalent in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am connecting to snowfalke database and fetch only 1 record. This record will have 21 columns. After i read them in python using connection, they return a tuple object.

I want to access the elements of tuple object with a name.

Preferrably i want to access these tuple elemts with the same name as column name from database.

In PL/SQL, we have something called as record type. And the elements in record can be accessed with a name

How do i do this in python?

Pseudocode ex:

```
tup_obj = connection.execute('select name, age, height, weight from table')
```

I want to access the tuple object like with names like this,

`tup_obj.name == 'Harish'`?

The above is only an example of the requiment. The below is the simulated data with same structure for my use case:

```
print(type(tup_obj))
print(tup_obj)

<class 'tuple'>
(101010, 5, 1, 200, 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 18075, 'text', 'text', 'text', 37, 2, 57, 'Y', 'S', 'S', 'text', 123, 'text')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary data structure to store and access like `tup_obj.name`

```
columns = ['name', 'age', 'height', 'weight']
data = [('a', 20, 170, 80)] # This will be your select query results
out = [dict(zip(columns, x)) for x in data]
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'a', 'age': 20, 'height': 170, 'weight': 80}]
```

Access using

```
out[0]['name'] # This will give string 'a'
```

EDIT:

For tuple, use directly

```
dict(zip(columns, data))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this in actual data.. getting error :  zip argument #2 must support iteration

Comment: You should post some data @HarikrishnanBalachandran in your question

Comment: I am sorry I can't do that. But thanks for the idea. I will try to fix the error.

Comment: @HarikrishnanBalachandran If you want people helping you in SO, you need to have a proper minimal example. Don't post the actual data. Post some dummy data with same structure.

Comment: have you tried using a `namedtuple` from the module `collections`

Comment: Yes. Why @Paul?

Comment: Updated my answer @HarikrishnanBalachandran. Also the query doesn't match the results. Selecting 4 columns shouldn't give these many values

Comment: Thanks It worked! Keeping the post open for sometime. Thanks for you time @Vishnudev